# Delete PHP MySQL Query Error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently having trouble deleted a photo from my database after a user uploads it.

This is my index file.

```
case "delete":
delete((int)$_POST['IdPhoto']);
break;
```

This is my API file (Trying to delete photo with specific ID for testing):

```
function delete($IdPhoto) {

$result = query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto='28'");
if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
```

}

That works perfectly. **How would I do it for any ID though or a specific one that I would grab through my iOS application?**

The application grabs IdPhoto, ID, Title automatically when it loads the image. I just need the proper query to determine it by the specific ID.

If it helps, this is how I load images:

```
    // load the last 50 photos from the "photos" table, also join the "login" so that you can fetch the 
    // usernames of the photos' authors
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: `DELETE FROM photos WHERE PhotoData = '$photoData' AND Title='$title'`

PD:insert_id don't return you the Id of DELETE... you need select before the id ;) 
(Almost, is better delete with id, than from title  / photodata ;))

Comment: Casting to `(int)` is **not** an alternative to [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: If our answers have helped you, you need to accept one of them, and if possible, upvote the others. This allows others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your delete statement is wrong. 
This

```
 
DELETE photos(PhotoData,Title) WHERE $photoData, $title
```

should be

```
 
   DELETE from photos WHERE PhotoData='$title';
```

When you delete from a table, the name of the column(s) that determine what row to delete is the only one needed to be specified. 
 
Secondly, since it seems that the column you are using for the deletion **(PhotoData)** is a string, you need to surround your value **($title)** with a single quotes **'$title'**. 
 
 
If you are still having problems with the deletion, it is possible that the value in the database and in **$title** do not match character by character. This can happen if there are spaces between the values in either case. You can either use **trim()** to remove any extra space before running the sql statement OR run a query like this:

```
 
  DELETE from photos WHERE PhotoData like '%$title%';
```

This will remove all rows having the same characters as the **$title** 
 
Hope this helps.

### Update

Since you want to pass in the **column's** and **row id**, your function should have 2 parameters.

```
 
function delete($IdPhoto, $row_id) {

   $result = query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto=$row_id");
   if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
   } else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
   }

}
```

So, just pass in 2 parameters and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you see my edits to tell me what my case statement should be as well?

Comment: Your delete function declaration accepts **3** parameters, but you only supplied it **one** in that **case** statement.

Comment: It could be anything as long as it matches the number of parameters specified **($id, $photoData, $title)** .

Comment: That should work; remove the single quotes though. Integers don't need them; only strings do.

Answer (score 0):

i think you shoud leran how to delete data by using sql

```
$result = query("DELETE from photos where title=$title");
```

Comment: then you can echo that sql to show if the sql is what you want

Answer (score 0):

your delete statement is incorrect. Use the following statement. You don't specify the columns for a delete query because your actually deleting a row.

```
DELETE FROM photos WHERE photoData = $variable
```

Answer (score 0):

your are missing a from clause in your deleting query add `from` into query

```
$result = query("DELETE from photos(PhotoData,Title) WHERE $photoData, $title");
```

try this one.

Comment: What should be my case request in my index file?

Comment: are you getting proper `$_POST['IdPhoto']` in index file?

Comment: you cannot directly call a function with it's name in codeigniter
you need to add `$this` so change line in index file with this `$this->delete((int)$_POST['IdPhoto']);`